# Derivative of all the parameters in Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, scikit-learn, derivative

$\mathcal{L}$ is the loss function, $\mathcal{L} = y_i \text{log} \sigma(z) + (1-y_i) \text{log} (1-\sigma(z))$, where $z = \sum_i w_ix_i$, with $w_i$ representing the weights and $x_i$ the features. Typically, it is required to take a derivative of $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $w_1$ or $w_2$. But I am required to provide derivative with respect to parameters which includes all weights.

Could anyone please recommend a solution or some tutorials? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by providing derivative wrt parameters which includes all weights'?'

Comment: What is $\sigma(x)$? The sigmoid function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{L}(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n)$ is a scalar loss function depending on multiple weights $w_i$ (neglecting features $x$ and labels $y$ for a moment) taking the gradient with respect to all would give you a vector

$\nabla \mathcal{L} = [\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial w_1}, ...,\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial w_n}]$.

Now you can calculate each individual component with the following formula, using the sigmoid derivative $\sigma'(x) = \sigma(x)(1 - \sigma(x))$ and chain rule:

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial w_i} = \frac{y_ix_i\sigma(z)(1 - \sigma(z))}{\sigma(z)} - \frac{(1 - y_i)x_i\sigma(z)(1-\sigma(z))}{1 - \sigma(z)}$.